# Android refresh activity while running thread

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

My question is : How can I update my UI while I'm running thread which is downloading some data over internet. If I do something like this :

```
public void getCollectionsInfo(Context context){
    jsonColl = new JsonCollection();
    final Context acontext = context;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           jsonColl.executeInsert(acontext);
        }}).start();

 }
```

How can I refresh my activity where I'm showing the data which I receive via `jsonColl.executeInsert(acontext);`.

Any kind of help or suggestions are welcomed!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use AsyncTask for this. where doInBackground() method work as background thread and progressUpdate() will update the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is as below.

```
public void getCollectionsInfo(Context context){
    jsonColl = new JsonCollection();
    final Context acontext = context;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           jsonColl.executeInsert(acontext);
mHandlerUpdateUi.post(mUpdateUpdateUi);    

        }}).start();

 }

final Handler mHandlerUpdateUi= new Handler();

    final Runnable mUpdateUpdateUi = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        //update ui here

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing Views is just a matter of calling `invalidate()` . What is the UI element in question?

- If it is a ListView, you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter
- If it is something else use the [UI Handler mechanism](http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/tag/handler/)

Comment: I need to refresh the listview where I show the data downloaded over internet.

Comment: How is the data attached to the list's adapter?

Comment: I'm saving all the data in sqlite database and populating the listview from database.

Comment: Then you have to refresh the Cursor by : creating a new cursor or `requery()` the cursor, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`